# Read/Write simultaneously to mapped network drive (samba file share)

Tags: windows, debian, samba, mapped-drive

I've been playing around with a home debian server, and so far it basically just hosts a samba network drive that I plan on using to store archived movies/tv shows/podcasts, etc. In the process of moving my collection over to the server, I've found that I can't access any of the shared files on the server while new files are being uploaded to it (ie; if I'm uploading a movie to the server from my desktop, if I try to play any of the shared files from, say, my laptop, VLC just freezes up).

I'm assuming this has something to do with the way I've set up read/write access, or is a matter of basically flipping a switch somewhere? Any ideas?

Comment: If you can read and write the directory then it won't be a Samba or permissions problem, more a network performance issue. It's like trying to walk the wrong way up a motorway at rush hour...

Comment: Could be a speed/duplex mismatch on the network interfaces.  Tell us more about how everything is connected.

Comment: What you describe is not standard for SAMBA. at the hardware level, the IO bus on the server can only deal with one stream at a time, but the server CPU should buffer streams and time-slice between them such that they appear to be happening simultaneously.